# Play framework return error: no suitable method found for ok(ArrayList<String[]>)]

Tags: playframework

I want play framework to send arraylist to my android application. So I can view the list on android app.
but the play framework cannot return ArrayList)
How can I solve this? 
Thank you.

```
public static Result get_LatestList() throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {
    String latestList = "";
    ArrayList<String[]> etList = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 

    MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    String pageNumber = body.asFormUrlEncoded().get("pageNumber")[0];
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/iea_db",
            "rt", "yt");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from List_Table;");
    while (rs.next()) {
        String[] oneSet = new String[4];

        oneSet[0] = rs.getString("userName");
        oneSet[1] = rs.getString("idName");
        oneSet[2] = rs.getString("comment");
        oneSet[3] = rs.getString("rank");
        etList.add(oneSet);
    }

    conn.close();                   
    return ok(etList);
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, but maybe remove the irrelevant tags and only leave the one with the version you are currently using (and the ones you can prove this applies to)?

Comment: sorry I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution: use Json 
In play framework, do this:

```
    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();

    result.put("draw", Integer.valueOf(params.get("draw")[0]));
    result.put("recordsTotal", iTotalRecords);
    result.put("recordsFilter", iTotalDisplayRecords);

    return ok(result);
```

In android, do this:

```
  @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... _uri) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(_uri[0]);
        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                httpResponse.getEntity().writeTo(outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
                return new JSONObject(outputStream.toString());
            } else {
                httpResponse.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```